# Angular 4 - Promise.all not working

Tags: angular, rest, promise

I'm using `Promise.all(...)` to wait for some REST calls to end before using the data I need from the server. The code structure is the following:

```
const promise1 = this.myService.myFirstRestFunction(a.id).toPromise().then(s => variable1 = s;);

const promise2 = this.myService.mySecondRestFunction(b.id).then(r => {
  this.myService.myThirdRestFunciont(r.id).then(c => variable2 = c);
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(p => {
  this.myService.getData(variable1.id, variable2.id)
    .subscribe(...);
});
```

But `variable2` is undefined when I try to get the `id` field. Is this related to the `myThirdRestFunction()` that is called inside? If this is the case, how can I manage such subsequential REST calls and wait for the most internal data to be fetched? Thanks.

**EDIT**: I changed my code following @Suren Srapyan and @Sachila Ranawaka answers.

```
const promise1 = this.myService.myFirstRestFunction(a.id).toPromise();

const promise2 = this.myService.mySecondRestFunction(b.id).then(r => {
  this.myService.myThirdRestFunciont(r.id);
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(p => {
  this.myService.getData(p[0].id, p[1].id)
    .subscribe(...);
});
```

In this case I get correctly `p[0]` but `p[1]` is still undefined. If I try to resolve the second promise, for example:

```
const promise2 = this.myService.mySecondRestFunction(b.id).then(r => {
      this.myService.myThirdRestFunciont(r.id).then(c => console.log(c));
    });
```

The object `c` is correctly logged, so `p[1]` should not be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to assign to the variables. `Promise.all` will resolve all promises if it could and pass their results into the `p` parameter as array.

Just return your data from the `then` functions and access via `p[0]` and `p[1]` in the `Promise.all(...).then(p => ...)`

```
const promise1 = this.myService.myFirstRestFunction(a.id).toPromise()

const promise2 = this.myService.mySecondRestFunction(b.id)
                               .then(r => this.myService.myThirdRestFuncion(r.id));

Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(p => {
  this.myService.getData(p[0].id, p[1].id).subscribe(...);
});
```

I don't know what your promises return, so I provide `p[0].id`. Change this according to your result.

For more beautiful code you can also destruct parameters

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(([var1, var2]) => {
    this.myService.getData(var1.id, var2.id).subscribe(...);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't resolve the first 2 promises. `Promise.all` will resolve all the promises for you

```
const promise1 = this.myService.myFirstRestFunction(a.id).toPromise() 
const promise2 = this.myService.mySecondRestFunction(b.id) 

Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(p => {
  this.myService.getData(variable1.id, variable2.id)
    .subscribe(...);
});
```